# How to check if the return value its null vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I start to make an application that automatic press a button on my webpage
the code its works perfect but how do i check if the return value its null?
This is my code

```
Public Class Form5
Dim CheckButton, skip_button As HtmlElement
Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    skip_button = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_button")
    CheckButton = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_button")

    skip_button.InnerText = "skip_button" 'Replace testID by the ID you want


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `If skip_button Is Nothing`?

Comment: Tank you @Ryan for the help i have try but its give me the same error i have try like this

Comment: If skip_button Is Nothing Then
            skip_button.InnerText = "skip_button" 'Replace testID by the ID you want
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("")

        End If

Comment: the error System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WindowsApplication1
  StackTrace:
       at WindowsApplication1.Form5.WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Monchique Discovery\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form5.vb:line 15

Comment: Well, that’s the opposite of what you’d want to do with `Nothing`. Use `IsNot Nothing`.

Comment: If skip_button IsNot Nothing Then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the result of [`GetElementById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) like the following:

```
Public Class Form5
    Dim CheckButton, skip_button As HtmlElement

    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
        MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        skip_button = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_button")
        CheckButton = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_button")

        If Not skip_button Is Nothing Then
            skip_button.InnerText = "skip_button" 'Replace testID by the ID you want
        End If

        If Not CheckButton Is Nothing Then
            'some code here
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```